# Как использовать языки, которые не поддерживаются официально в "windows phone"?

Tags: c#, локализация, windows-phone-7

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Насколько я понял, сейчас в WP7 язык приложения по умолчанию подстраивается под язык в настройках (регион + язык -> язык интерфейса)
Статей по данной тематике довольно много, и все довольно просто. Но существует проблема. WP7 поддерживает не так уж много языков, а
у меня например есть необходимость использовать языки, которые не входят в список поддерживаемых.

Попробовал было установить язык напрямую:

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ыы-ЫЫ");
    // ыы-ЫЫ - аббревиатура никому не известного языка
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Однако так сделать не получилось, т.к. на неизвестные языки программа ругается. С известными все проходит.

Как можно использовать такие языки? Есть у кого идеи?

---

[обновлено 10.09.2012]

Так, более актуальный вопрос:

Я тут внезапно заметил, что после смены языка требуется перезагрузка ОС. Это вообще нормально? И можно ли как-то эту фигню обойти?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Другими словами, *как расширить локализацию в WP7*?

А Unicode символы для букв языка "Ыы" уже существуют?

Comment: @avp, вы про Ыы всерьез или это просто шутка юмора? :) Понятно, что там другие две буквы из латиницы.

Comment: @Olter, очевидно, что в названии локали латинские буквы (какие-нибудь kz_KZ). 

Вам надо разбираться с добавлением локалей в WP7. Возможно (предположение) там есть алиасы. Тогда легко. Иначе надо ваять все файлы (или в WP7 соавсем другой механизм?) описаия локали и ставить ее.

Где-то в мануалах типа "Руководство системного администратора" такая инфа должна быть.

Comment: - Логика неверная - текущий выбранный язык приложения должен зависеть только от глобальных настроек и не должен меняться сам по себе. Вы же просто добавляете переведенные ресурсы для [**набора поддерживаемых языков**][1] и ждете сообщения сверху о текущих языковых настроек на одну из поддерживаемых `Windows Phone.` В случае, если для данного языка у вас нет специфичных ресурсов, вы дефолтитесь на ресурсы для стандартной `CultureInfo`.

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202918(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: - Если поддержка `"ыы-ЫЫ"` настолька важна, что без нее не обойтись, то лично я бы записывал нужные ресурсы для любой неинвариантной `CultureInfo,` поддерживаемой `Windows Phone OS` (которая наиболее близка к `"ыы-ЫЫ"` в плане общих правил форматирования). Дальше, предположительно, можно реализовать кастомную логику установки `CultureInfo,` опирающуюуся на знание того, что в ресурсах для такой-то `CultureInfo` у вас на самом деле сакраментальные знания, касающиеся `"ыы-ЫЫ".`

- Так можно обойти `PlatformNotSupportedException,` хотя, конечно, решение нехорошее.

Comment: Насчет "неверной логики", я и сам понимаю. Но вот надо. Вариант с использованием чужой CultureInfo выглядит жутко коряво, но приму к сведению. Буду думать дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения описан здесь:

[Localization with an unsupported language](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/9b6cddba-d7f4-4206-b6bd-7ffee15a4bb9/)

На первый взгляд - работает. Как проверю свой вариант, отпишусь о результатах.

---

Сделал, действительно работает, хотя подводных камней довольно много. Как будет время - распишу решение подробно.

---

Итак:

**Возможности для выстрела в ногу** (обратить внимание тем, кто сначала написал в стиле, рекомендованном Майкрософт(как я), а потом вынужден будет реализовывать новый язык. Все обращения к ресурсам придется переписывать. Это печально. Поехали):

В классе LocalizedResources.cs путь к ресурс-менеджеру описывается в стиле:

```
_rman = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("AppName.Folder.ResourcesApp", typeof(ResourcesApp).Assembly);
```

для известных языков

где:

*AppName* - имя приложения

*Folder* - папка, в которой лежат ресурсы. У меня  это была папка Resources. Если в корне - соответственно ничего не пишем.

*ResourcesApp* - то, как называются наши файлы для известных языков. В примере он один и называется Resource(для английского). Т.е. для английского это будет Resource.resx или Resource.en-US.resx или Resource.en-UK.resx, для русского Resource.ru-RU.resx и.т.п. Постфикс(а.к.а ru-RU) не имеет значения, нужный язык потом выберется через метод **SwitchCulture**.

для неизвестных соответственно используется перегруженный метод **SwitchCulture**:

```
public void SwitchCulture(string UnsupportedCulture)
        {
            _rman = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("App.Resources.XXX" + UnsupportedCulture, typeof(ResourcesApp).Assembly);
        }
```

где *XXX* это то, как **полностью** называется файл с ресурсами для неизвестного языка.

В примере эти файлы называются Resource_Klingon.resx и Resource_Vulcan.resx.

// там должно быть подчеркивание между словами, почему-то не отображается

У меня было соответственно ResourcesApp.LanguageName.resx

Т.е. в примере путь выглядел, как **"PhoneApp1.Resource_"**, в моем случае **"App.Resources.ResourcesApp."**.

Для обращения к ресурсам используется метод **Get**. Соответственно все обращения в стиле:

```
Resources.resourceName
```

придется заменить на

```
LocalizedResources.Resources.Get("resourceName")
```

Аналогичная ситуация со связыванием через *Binding*. Вместо обращений, типа:

```
"{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.someName, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

используются

```
{"Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Converter={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, ConverterParameter=someName}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать кастомную культуру - [CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx):

> Определяет пользовательский язык и региональные параметры, которые или являются новыми, или основываются на другом языке и региональных параметрах или на другой стране и регионе.

Пример внизу статьи.

Comment: Наверняка `Register` под `WP7` сфейлится. Хотя попробовать все равно можно.

Comment: Не подойдет. Собственно, в самой статье даже указано, что поддержка только под .Net Framework и винду. Ни о Silverlight, ни о Windows Phone ни слова.

Comment: Оу, да. Прощу прощения, не обратил внимания на версии.